# Getting UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Pagination.paginate is not a function on Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code and receiving UnhandledPromise warning.

```
class Pagination {
  async paginate(filterResult, pageNumber) {
    try {
      const page = pageNumber;
      const limit = 10;
      const filter = await filterResult

      const startIndex = (page - 1) * limit;
      const endIndex = page * limit;

      return filter.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = Pagination;
```

I am trying to paginate the result from the query.

```
class PlaceFilter {
  //Filter by Categories
  static async filterResult(result, types) {
    try {
      const placeByCategory = [];
      const places = await result;
      if (favSports == 'All') {
        return places;
      } else {
        for (const place of places) {
          let str = place.category.join(',');
          let arr = types.split(',');
          console.log(place);
          console.log(`arr: ${arr}`);
          console.log(`str: ${str}`);
          for (let types of arr) {
            if (str.indexOf(types) !== -1) {
              placeByCategory.push(place);
            }
          }
        }
        return placeByCategory;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

module.exports = PlaceFilter;
```

This is the first query. And, both are tied up with like this

```
const paginatedResult = await Pagination.paginate(filterResult, pageNumber);
```

in controller. Why am I getting UnhandledPromise warning and what could be a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Pagination.paginate` is indeed not a function. `new Pagination().paginate` would be one. This is because you forgot to make your `paginate` function `static`!

```js
class Pagination {
  static async paginate(filterResult, pageNumber) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

As for why it's an unhandled rejection: You probably forgot to add a `.catch(e => someErrorHandlingHere(e))` to the place where you call your outermost async function from (probably non-async) code without `await`ing it.